# Does Mybatis support neo4j cypher？

Tags: cypher, mybatis

```
MATCH (n:#{name})-[r]->(m:#{name}) RETURN n.name as sn,r.name as rn,m.name as tn
```

It seems like #{} is not working here, I use ${} instead and it worked

print error sql

```
MATCH (n:$1)-[r]->(m:$2) RETURN n.name as sn,r.name as rn,m.name as tn
```

parameter is right, so how to use #{} in cypher?

- neo4j jdbc version 4.0.5
- mybatis version 3.5.9

Comment: Try `#{name,typeHandler=org.apache.ibatis.type.ObjectTypeHandler}`. If it does not work, write the same statement using plain JDBC code (with `PreparedStatement`) and add it to the question. Then we may be able to translate it into a MyBatis mapper statement. I'm not familiar with Neo4j driver, but this [comment](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc/issues/180#issuecomment-428885326) may help.

Comment: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc/issues/150#issuecomment-396839385
so it cannot use dynamic parameters for Label, thank you for your help